# Can I use PHP's SoapClient to parse a SOAP response, without making the HTTP request?

Tags: php, xml, soap, soap-client

I'm currently dealing with an archaic payment processor that makes connecting to their service as hard as possible (including a custom client SSL cert, with a password, plus basic HTTP Auth after that). Long story short, I can't use SoapClient to make the request, but I have been able to do it with cURL.

I now have the response in a string, can I use `SoapClient` to parse it? I'd rather not have to parse it manually as a regular XML, since I'd have to duplicate a lot of functionality, like throwing a sensible exception when finding a `<SOAP:Fault>`, for example.

Comment: Couldn't you just take whatever response you got using cURL, serve it up through a separate script and point SoapClient at that instead?  Essentially, you'd be making a really simple SOAP proxy that doesn't really do anything except pass back whatever you got from cURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

(just answering this for posterity. Based on the lack of evidence to the contrary, you apparently can't use SoapClient to parse a SOAP response you already have)

Answer (score 0):

You can define context using `context` option of [`SoapClient`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) to tell SoapClient to use SSL certificates etc. Context may be created using [`stream_context_create`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) with [lots of options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.php)

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work for me. That's not what I'm asking, though, I already spent too many hours getting that connection to work, and I have the SOAP response. Can I parse it with something more SOAP-specific that SimpleXML?

Comment: Hmm... May be this http://nusoap.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nusoap/lib/class.soap_parser.php?view=markup ?

Comment: @DanielMagliola Any particular reason you are opposed to SimpleXML?

Comment: I'm not "opposed to" it, I just want to take the simplest path, and something that understands SOAP is easier than something that doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Let's for a second imagine you had called SoapClient::__doRequest() and it returned your XML SOAP response into a variable called **$response**.

```
<?php

   //LOAD RESPONSE INTO SIMPLEXML
   $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);

   //REGISTER NAMESPACES
   $xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap-env', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
   $xml->registerXPathNamespace('somenamespace', 'http://www.somenamespace/schema/');
   //...REGISTER OTHER NAMESPACES HERE...

   //LOOP THROUGH AND GRAB DATA FROM A NAMESPACE
   foreach($xml->xpath('//somenamespace:MessageHeader') as $header)
   {
      echo($header->xpath('//somenamespace:MyData')); 
   }

   //...ETC...

?>
```

That is just some example/pseudo code (not tested and won't work as-is). My point is that you manually acquired the SOAP response so now all you have to do is parse it. [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) is *one* solution you could use to do that.

Comment: Additionally, here are a bunch of resources available for parsing XML: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php

Comment: Yeah, that's precisely what I was trying to avoid, and what I'm doing anyway, apparently, because SoapClient assumes you need HTTP requests, which is wrong, but whatever. Thanks!